# I Want To Give My Children Japanese Names, As I Will Naturalize Myself Soon, Can I Use Jinmeiyō Kanji To Create ANY Name?

Tags: kanji, names

For example, we like the names Ren (蓮/廉) & Touka (藤香). Could we create the name, Rentouka, combining the two?

Comment: No matter what name you give it, I'm sure it will be accepted as long as it is not too terrible. Personally, I don't like it when parents give me that name because it seems meaningless... Well, I guess it still is better than [these](https://ranking.goo.ne.jp/column/6010/ranking/52086/).

Comment: Are you sure it will be accepted? I don't want her to stand out too much or have people think her parents gave her a weird name. What name don't you like it when parents give you? Ren?

Comment: Uh, I meant it will be accepted by your local office, not people around (or, in general) you guys. What I'd dislike is not Ren or Touka, it's Rentouka. Ren or Touka would be perfectly fine I think.

Comment: It also makes me think of レンタカー, which may not be intended.

Comment: Skye-AT understood, so it's just best to select a currently existing name :)

Comment: @OliverGardner Think it this way; You (probably) haven't seen someone got named "Amandajanice (put your favorite surname)", that's what you're trying to do. One name alone is enough to function as a name.

Comment: @Skye-AT it's difficult to make a perfect comparison to English in that way, since I think there's more acceptance of uniqueness in names generally, and combining two names into one is actually not that unusual of a phenomenon. Though, yes, for whatever reason "Amandajanice" does sound strange. Perhaps because of the length and number of syllables.

Comment: @Leebo Oh really? another knowledge to my book. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule regarding how to combine jinmeiyō/jōyō kanji to create a name. So technically and legally speaking, 蓮藤香 and 廉藤香 are valid names, simply because they consist only of jinmeiyō/jōyō kanji. I'm sure a local office will not refuse this name.

However, of course that does not mean every kanji combination is **natural**. (Vrleio is a legally valid English name but that does not mean it's as natural as Oliver, right?) Judging whether a certain name is good or bad is a subjective matter, and is not within the scope of this site. At least, I'd say 蓮藤香 or 廉藤香 is unique and eye-catching.

Comment: So even if a combination would appear "offensive" in some sense (I have no examples though), it would still be accepted?

Comment: @a20 An extreme example is the case of [悪魔 ("Devil")](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1994-01-15-mn-12064-story.html). 蓮藤香 is not like this, though.

Comment: Interesting... here is a follow up: https://anohitohaima.tokyo/post-280/

Comment: I am most concerned about whether this would make her stand out in a negative way. Unconventional or if it would look like a Gaijin just trying to make unnecessary names that have a 'cool meaning' if you follow? I want a nice name but fitting in is important, no sense giving her a name she will have to explain 1000 times throughout her life haha